# scroll horizontal al desplegar elementos ocultos se desubica del top actual

Tags: css, html5

tengo un contenedor que dentro suyo, tiene elementos ocultos que se despliegan al dar click en un botón, esto genera que el scroll haga un recorrido hacia arriba y lo que necesito es que se conserve en la posición actual y que el recorrido lo haga el contenido oculto, hacia abajo y no el botón de despliegue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Andrés! Podrías crear un [mcve] donde podamos ver el código en acción?

Comment: Andres podrias dejar ver un poco mejor ese codigo que de html que tienes hay; recortalo

Comment: Por lo que veo, el código no despliega en atributos display(block,none) o visibility (hidden, show), lo que hace actualmente es que con el click, crea el código html y con el click para cerrar, destruye el código (no aparece en el inspector), por lo que no podría editarlo con clases y efectos animados, y como no soy programador no entiendo como se pudiera conservar el código, no creo que se pueda hacer mucho =(